# how to display each file in directory randomly once then display it again after i finish displaying all the file

Tags: python

this is a music player simulation instead of playing the song I will print the title  of each song I played and get the position of each file in the directory

```
import os 
import sys 
import time 
import random 
import logging


# main: this is the main function of this Python
# def main(argv):
    count=c=1
    #make the program run for ever
    while True:
        #get the files from the comand line arguments 
        #check if the file end with mp3
        songs =  [f for f in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]) if f.endswith('.mp3')]
        #get the total number of files
        for (i, file) in enumerate(songs,1):
            #randamly select a song
            file = random.choice(songs)
            print ("{} ({},{}):playing file {}".format (count ,i , c ,file))
            count+=1
            #
            time.sleep(3)
        c+=1   

# begin gracefully
# if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: There is no question. See [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework", and [ask] more generally. As well, the description in the body is much broader than the title, so please clarify which part you're asking about. Also the code snippet has a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really interesting problem, here's my attempt at answering your question:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import random
import time


# Searches for all files in all folders of a directory, returns a list of paths
def find_files(file_directory):
    file_list = list()
    for filepath, folder, files in os.walk(file_directory):
        file_list += list(Path(filepath)/file for file in files)
    return file_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_music = True
    file_directory = r"C:\path\to\music_files"
    file_list = find_files(file_directory=file_directory)
    already_played = list()

    print("There are", len(file_list), "music files")
    while play_music:

        # Makes sure there are still songs that haven't been played
        if len(file_list) > 0:
            # randomly picks a file, find its position in the file list
            random_file = random.choice(file_list)
            random_file_index = file_list.index(random_file)

            # removes from the list and moves it to the already played list
            already_played.append(file_list.pop(random_file_index))

        else:
            print("No more songs left, refreshing list")
            file_list = find_files(file_directory=file_directory)

        print("Playing", random_file)


        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can you tell me how to get the position of each file?

Comment: If you're talking about a list of items and you want the index (position) you use `index = some_list.index(some_variable)` and that will find the first item that matches and return its index. I've used this above where it says `random_file_index = file_list.index(random_file)`, thats the files position (index) in the list.

Comment: I tried that but it just gives me random numbers does not match the position of the file in the directory

Answer (score 0):

You must probably look at `pathlib` module of python.

To get a list of all mp3 files from some path, you can try:

```
from pathlib import Path
mp3_files = list(Path("your/path").glob("**/*.mp3"))
```

You are finding the files inside the `while` loop which is not very efficient thing to do. Secondly why do you need the second for loop?

**Edit**

Because you say, you don't want to play a file that has been already played. I would suggest to look at the `set` data structure.

```py
mp3_files = set(mp3_files)

#select randomly somefile from the set
selected_file = mp3_files.pop()
```

The function `pop` will not only arbitrarily select a file but will also remove it from the set. That you don't have to keep track of what files you have already played.

**Edit #2**

Putting together everything

```py
def main():
    mp3_files = set(Path("your/path").glob("**/*.mp3")
    while True:
        selected_file = mp3_files.pop()
```

Comment: Simpler: `selected_file = random.choice(mp3_files)`

Comment: all songs has to play once before you start playing a song a second time and I need the position of each mp3 in the directory

Comment: it will play the first song over and over again

Comment: are you listing the files inside the while loop?